# Select certain terms in an expression

Tags: pattern-matching, filtering

I would like to have a function to select terms containing q[i] terms in expressions, for example, for an expression

```
a q[i]+b +c q[j]+d
```

I would like the function to return

```
a q[i]+c q[j]
```

as result. Also at the same time, for a bare

```
q[i]
```

the same function would return

```
q[i]
```

How to realize such function? Thanks

Comment: Here is another question related to this question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190393/select-certain-term-containing-some-patterns-and-confusing-pattern-alternatives

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pattern-based approach.

```
fn[x_. y_q + z_.] := x y + fn[z]
_fn = 0;

a q[i] + b + c q[j] + d // fn

q[i] // fn
```

> ```
> a q[i] + c q[j]
>
> q[i]
> ```

Answer (score 4):

```
expr = a q[i] + b + c q[j] + d;
f = DeleteCases[#, Except[_.  _q], If[Head[#] === q, 0, 1]] &
f @ expr
```

> a q[i] + c q[j]

```
f @ q[i]
```

> q[i]

Alternatively,

```
f2 = Select[#, Function[x, If[Head@# === q, True, Not @ FreeQ[x, _q]]]] &;
f2 @ expr
```

> a q[i] + c q[j]

```
f2 @ q[i]
```

> q[i]

Comment: This realize the first requirement, but for the bare $q[i]$, it returns $q[]$

Comment: @XiaoaiX, I will update if i find a fix.

Comment: thanks, from your answer, I also got confused about how the Select and Cases handle the List argument, see the question I just post here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189270/why-cases-and-select-treat-the-list-differently