# Why Cases and Select treat the List differently?

Tags: pattern-matching, filtering

Look at these two examples:

```
In[1]:=Select[f[i], MatchQ[_f]]
Out[1]:=f[]

In[2]:=Cases[f[i],_f]
Out[2]:={}
```

It seems that the Select take $f[i]$ as List, but Cases do not.

I also can not understand why the first gives that answer.

Thanks.

Comment: ref / Select / Generalizations&Extensions / #1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) preserves the head of the original expression, while [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) always returns the result in a [`List`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html).
2. `Select` operates only at [level one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15567/121), whereas `Cases` accepts a [*levelspec*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29750/121).

Specifically your first output is equivalent to these:

```
Part[f[i], {}]

Delete[f[i], 1]
```

The second can be made to match by expanding the *levelspec* to include level zero:

```
Cases[f[i], _f, {0, 1}]
```

> ```
> {f[i]}
> ```

Recommended reading:

- [What best practices or performance considerations are there for choosing between Cases, Position, Pick and Select?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2/121)
- [Head and everything except Head?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2449/121)
- [How to get Cases to wrap results in an arbitrary head?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31754/121)

Comment: The essence of (1) is that `Select[f[i], MatchQ[_f]]` matches *nothing* and only returns an empty expression with head `f`. It is the same as `Select[f[i], MatchQ[_somethingelse]]`. The recommended answers are very informative btw.