# Select certain term containing some patterns and confusing pattern Alternatives in FreeQ

Tags: pattern-matching, expression-manipulation, filtering

I am considering a function `termsContain[func_,list_]` which select in an expression `func` the terms containing the ones in the list. The `func` in general is a sum of some terms and could also be only one term, for example,

```
in[1]:= termsContain[a + b + c + a x +b y, {x,y}]
out[1]= a x+b y

in[2]:= termsContain[a + b + c + f[a x +c]+b y, {a x}]
out[2]=f[c + a x]

in[3]:= termsContain[a x , {a x}]
out[3]= a x

in[4]:=  termsContain[a + b + c + a x[i] y[j] +b x[l] y[m] , {x[_]y[_]}]
out[4]= a x[i] y[j]+b x[l] y[m]
```

I came up with this :

```
termsContain[func_, list_] :=  func /. (Longest[u___?(Not[FreeQ[#, Alternatives @@ list]] &)] + v___) :> (Plus[u]);
```

This works fine for the first three examples, but not for the last one. For the last one, this gives only zero

```
out[4]=0
```

Try another example which is also not as expected:

```
in[5]:=termsContain[a + b + c + a x[i] y[j] +b x[l] y[m] +c f[x[l] y[m]], {x[_]y[_]}]
out[5]= c f[x[l] y[m]]
```

I thought it should give `a x[i] y[j] +b x[l] y[m] +c f[x[l] y[m]]`. How to understand these results? I did some experiments, the problem seems to be the `FreeQ` combined with `Alternatives`. The `Alternatives` seems not to take one argument, that is, `Alternatives[x[_] y[_]]` does not match  `x[_] y[_]` as I thought. See these examples,

```
in[6]:=FreeQ[a x[i] y[j] +b x[l] y[m], x[_] y[_]]
out[6]= False
in[7]:=FreeQ[a x[i] y[j] +b x[l] y[m], Alternatives[x[_] y[_]]]
out[7]= True
```

But the `out[2]` and the `out[3]` seem to give the correct answer. Why? I am really confused. And how to modify the code to give the expected answer? Thanks!

Appendix:
We can test this, for a special case without using `Alternatives`

```
   in[8]:= c a[i] x[j] + d f[a[l] x[m]] + f + l +   d a[l] x[n] /. (Longest[u___?(Not[FreeQ[#, a[i_] x[j_]]] &)] + v___) :> (Plus[u])
   out[8]= d f[a[l] x[m]] + c a[i] x[j] + d a[l] x[n]
```

It works here. So the problem really is in `Alternatives`. `FreeQ` combined with `Alternatives` is really confusing, look at these

```
in[9]:= FreeQ[a x y, a x ]
out[9]= False
in[10]:= FreeQ[a x y, a x | y ]
out[10]= False
in[11]:= FreeQ[a x y, a x | a y ]
out[11]= True
```

Modify the `in[2]` a little

```
in[12]:= termsContain[a + b + c + f[a x y + c] + b x y, { x }]
out[12]= b x y + f[c + a x y]
in[13]:= termsContain[a + b + c + f[a x y + c] + b x y, { a x }]
out[13]=0
in[14]:= termsContain[a + b + c + f[a x y + c] + b x y, { b y }]
out[14]=0
```

Edit:

At last, I come to this realization,

```
termsContain[func_, list_] := func /. (Longest[
   u___?(Not[And @@ (Through[(FreeQ[#] & /@ list)[#]])] &)] + 
  v___) :> (Plus[u]);
```

which is what I want. But I still would like to know how to understand the `Alternatives` in `FreeQ`.

Comment: This implementation is very  slow. I guess Longest is time consuming. It seems to be better to use the methods given here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189268/select-certain-terms-in-an-expression?noredirect=1&lq=1